# Multiple network Adapters switching

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, proxy, ethernet

I have a multi-network adapter workstation. Lets say its a ethernet and a wifi. The ethernet is somewhat restrictive, blocking alot of blogs and other resources, and is behind a proxy server that f*** things up for some indie-apps that i use (such as genymotion), but it is ultra-fast. The wifi in another hand is open and not behind a proxy, but is slow... dead-slow... 75kbps max speed slow...

Everyday I have to keep removing the ethernet cable so the wifi takes over... I want a better, more cooperative solution... What I'm looking for is a configuration that gives me something like "Try first using the ethernet connection, if that fails, try using the wifi"! a even better solution would be MPTCP, but that is a long shot... So any ideas on how to do this?

Details:

- Using Mavericks (latest version)
- Macbook Pro Retina (early 2013)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do that without a proper router. You will have to mark some packets/connections to go through one gateway or another.

The only thing you can do is changing they metric of the interface and set the default one, much like plugging and unplugging the ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

In general, given the extreme difference in speed, you may wish to consider getting around the limitations posed by your proxy, rather than sending anything over the super-slow wifi.

Not all proxies are equally good at blocking traffic. For instance, they are often easily pierced by using a VPN to some outside server. You may rent a cheap VPS service for as low as 1 euro a month, set up a VPN over tcp port 443 (which is nearly never blocked) and off you go.

If instead your proxy blocks DNS requests, you use [dnscrypt](http://dnscrypt.org/) which allows you to encrypt DNS requests and send them over any port you wish, this is how I circumvent limitations at my home institution.

It is rare that proxies block both of these channels, they generally do a rather bad job at blocking traffic, luckily for us.